# find duplicate records sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i know how to find duplicate values using count()
but my question is how can i find duplicate values starting with some letter like'A' or 'K'

i have a table tblmytable like this

```
id    rollnumber    city  fess
1   A100156       Ajamer 450
2   P102555       Pune   450
3   A100156       Ajamer 450
4   P102555       Pune   450
```

The query

```
select rollnumber,count(rollnumber) AS COUNTOF
from tblmytable
group by rollnumber
having count(rollnumber) > 1
order by rollnumber
```

gives me this result

```
rollnumber countof
    A100156       2
    P102555       2
```

i want to find duplicate roll numbers starting with 'A'

like this how can i modify the query

Comment: Add a `where` clause with a `LIKE 'A%'` condition

Comment: Edit your question and provide appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: use `where rollnumber like 'A%'`

Answer (score 2):

Just put a WHERE clause on

```
select rollnumber,count(rollnumber) AS COUNTOF
from tblmytable
where rollnumber like 'A%'
group by rollnumber
having count(rollnumber)>1 order by rollnumber
```